# Where does the Kullback-Leibler come from?

Tags: entropy, kullback-leibler

Let $p(x)$ be some *"true"* distribution which we want to model using a simpler distribution $q(x)$. Why is the KL divergence $$KL(q||p)=\int q(x)\log{\frac{q(x)}{p(x)}}$$ a good way to represents the loss of information in using $q$ instead of $p$? Is the KL divergence some *"ad hoc method"* or it has a deeper meaning? Shouldn't be the entropy difference $$H(q)-H(p)$$ the right quantity to use?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen it's not a duplicate. I'm not asking why isn't the KL a metric.

Comment: Thats notwhat you have written

Comment: Read through all the answers there; I think you will find the information you need. If it isn't what you want / you still have a question afterwards, 
come back here & edit your question to state what you learned & what you still 
need to know. Then we can provide the information you need without just 
duplicating material elsewhere that already didn't help you.

Answer (score 6):

KL divergence is very closely related to entropy. It helps to understand the motivation behind the expression for entropy.

For some distribution $p(x)$ we call $h(x) = -\log p(x)$ the *information* received by observing variable $x$. It's called "information" because it has the nice property that if we observe two completely independent events, $x$ and $y$, then the information gained is the sum of the information gained from each event. I.e. if $x$ and $y$ are independent, $p(x,y) = p(x) p(y),$ then $h(x,y) = -\log p(x) - \log p(y) = h(x) + h(y).$ Likewise, if $x$ and $y$ are completely mutually occurring, then it follows that observing $x$ and $y$ simply gives us the exact same information as observing $x$ alone. That is $p(x,y) = p(x) \implies h(x,y) = h(x).$ Also, this form of $h(x)$ ensures that the information gained is always positive, and more information is gained by observing events that are less likely.

To that end, *entropy* is the expected amount of information gained by observing a variable drawn from a distribution $p$. That is,
$$
H[p] = E[h_p(x)] = \int p(x) h_p(x) dx = - \int p(x) \log p(x) dx,
$$

where I'm calling $h_p(x)$ the information gained from observing $x$ if $x$ is drawn from distribution $p.$

The KL divergence is often used in situations where $p$ is some unknown *true* distribution, and $q$ is a proxy distribution that we're using to estimate $p.$ $KL(p \mid \mid q)$ is the *expected* difference in information received by observing $x$ if $q$ was the true distribution, vs if $p$ was the true distribution, and that expectation is taken over a single distribution. Another way of saying it is that it's the expected *additional* information we need to receive from observing $x$ in order to get all the information we need.

Suppose you couldn't draw from $p(x)$ but could only evaluate it for a given $x$ (or, at the very least, you could evaluate the ratio $p(x)/q(x)$). But you could draw from  your proxy distribution $q(x),$ and you want to learn $p.$ Then the expected deficit of information you gain (or the expected additional information you *need* to gain in order to learn $p$) is

$$
KL(q \mid \mid p) = E_q[h_p(x) - h_q(x)] = \int q(x) [h_p(x) - h_q(x)] dx = \int q(x) \log \frac{q(x)}{p(x)} dx.
$$

I gave an intuitive interpretation of the $KL$ divergence, but one thing about this form is that it's guaranteed to be non-negative. Even though individual instances of $q(x) \log \frac{q(x)}{p(x)}$ might be negative, the instances where $q>p$ will outweigh the others. (More explicitly, the [Gibbs' inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs%27_inequality) guarantees that it's non-negative.) This means that, as long as $p(x)$ is the *true* distribution you will always need more information if you're using a proxy, $q(x),$ to draw from. By contrast, your suggestion of using $H[q] - H[p]$ has no such guarantee.

Comment: " $KL(p||q)$ is the expected difference.. single distribution" why do you do that? The expected difference in information would be to me $$E_p[h_p(x)]-E_q[h_q(x)]$$ I don't see any meaning in the expression $E_q[h_p(x)]$

Comment: The entropy difference is not an expectation of anything, because it's not summed over a single probability distribution. If you had two variables, $a$ and $b$, and wanted to calculate the expected difference $E[a-b]$ you wouldn't do $\sum p_i a_i - \sum q_i b_i$ because that's just a meaningless quantity. You would evaluate $\sum p_i (a_i - b_i).$ The thing you're trying to learn is a probability distribution. $E_q[h_p(x)]$ is the expected information you learned about $p$ if you're drawing from distribution $q.$ (E.g. if $p>0$ only in regions where $q=0$ you'll learn nothing about $p.$)